# Как осуществить вызов userControl при помощи паттерна MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Привет всем.

Решил измотать себя, при помощи WPF. Ну и конечно, паттерн MVVM :)

Разумеется, сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, как при помощи MVVM паттерна открыть UserControl?

Конечно, нет проблем это сделать в самом View. Но, как же MVVM . Кто-нибудь может привести пример в пару строк кода Как мне это реализовать. дело в том что в интернете есть много описания паттерна MVVM, все ограничиваются написанием калькулятора, то бишь на одной форме. В принципе я тоже пишу всегда на одной форме но в нужные моменты подставляю контрол.  эмитируя переход на другую форму. Я не знаю правильно это или нет. но, мне так удобней.

Comment: Что значит "открыть контрол"?

Comment: @Алексей Саровский Да наверное, правильнее было описать принцип программы.

Запускается программа. Открывается форма на которой размещен UserControl например Приветствия и описания программы.

потом пользователь жмет кнопку далее и открывается следующий userControl скажем с формой регистрации и.т.д . При этом разумеется контрол с приветствием закрывается

Comment: Все, понял Вас. Хм... это как-то не очень православно, по-моему, на одной форме менять UserControl-ы. Разве что разместить на форме все UserControl, поставить Visible в false у нужных и этот Visible привязать к ViewModel. В нем уже выставлять Visible в true/false как нужно - но костыль жесткий слишком. А можно узнать, почему 1 форма именно?

Comment: Даже сам не знаю :). Я Писал программки на WInForm. Так мне лень было каждый раз, создавать новую форму. Делать для нее настройки и все такое . А так Есть одна Форма, можно сказать дезаин программы один, просто подстовляешь новые контролы и все пучком.

Честно сказать я совсем слаб в программировании. Мне это просто интересно я самоучка. несмотря на то что я написал программу для моего знакомого. У которого есть свой биллиард бар. так я дал ему программу которая считала сколько времени его клиент играл за 

столом и на какую сумму деллал заказы

Comment: Если можете, то подскажите как правильно.

Comment: Маленькая поправка. я не лепил контролы на одну форуму. по принципу visible.

я их добавляв в нужный момент. this.Controls.Add(сам контрол);

по этому не было большой путаницы

Comment: Ну правильного ничего в мире нет... Но я бы все-таки лепил отдельные формы. С ними же мучиться совсем не нужно - почитайте про IoC-контейнеры (LightInject, например) и сразу куча проблем, которые возникают при многооконном приложении, отпадает. Просто если так как Вы делать - слишком много ответственности у классов и слишком много кода, наверно.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24473/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 6):

Популярный путь такой.

Вы прописываете

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    VM activePageVM;
    public VM ActivePageVM
    {
        get { return activePageVM; }
        set { activePageVM = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    // обвеска для INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

обычным образом. Теперь, ваше окно выглядит так:

```
<Window ...>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ACtivePageVM}"/>
</Window>
```

(можете ещё вокруг добавить общую обвеску, нужную на всех страницах).

Осталось только сделать так, чтобы ваш `ContentPresenter` выбирал правильный `UserControl` в зависимости от типа VM. Это делается очевидной диспетчеризацией через `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstVM}">
    <ui:FirstUserControl/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondVM}">
    <ui:SecondUserControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Эту диспетчеризацию поместите в `App.xaml` или куда-то ещё, где она видна в главном окне. Если вам надо где-то локально перекрыть отображение для какого-то типа, пользуйтесь локальными ресурсами, они всегда имеют приоритет.

Comment: @VlalD Спасибо за ответ. Все вроде понятно. Только у меня выдает ошибку NotifyPropertyChanged();

Comment: Ну, это ж набросок кода. Вам, понятно, нужно реализовать стандартным образом `INotifyPropertyChanged`. У вас ещё на многоточие в `Window` будет ругаться. И для `DataTemplate`'ов вам нужно будет указать пространства имён `vm` и `ui`.

Comment: @VlaID Естественно я добавил, пространство имен. Иначе на меня ругался бы еще и интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @ГеннадийПисарев: Посмотрите, как заимплементировано, например, [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (класс `DemoCustomer`).