# WPF MVVM: Как пробросить модель в Page, динамически загруженную во Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я создал Frame, который динамически загружает страницы по пути в параметре  `SelectedNode.ViewerPath`:

Страницы грузятся нормально. 
Но вопрос в том, **как пробросить ViewModel на загружаемые страницы?**

Пробовал делать вот так:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedNode.ViewerPath}" DataContext="{Binding SelectedNode}"/>
```

Но, по очевидным причинам, это не работает.

Comment: А не легче просто отказаться от Frame?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Конечная цель - предоставить возможность разработчикам независимо друг от друга пилить вьюхи для разрабатываемых классов.  Сейчас смотрю еще в сторону DataTemplateSelector, но вариант с Frame мне кажется более универсальным.

Comment: Используйте `ContentPresenter` и будет вам счастье. Пример можно глянуть например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428226/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, посмотрю