# Событие в C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события

Есть 2 ViewModel`и AuthViewModel и LoginViewModel.
В LoginView есть Frame который контент которого LoginControl а у него контекст AuthViewModel. И в этом LoginControl есть кнопка при нажатии на которую должно срабатывать события LoginCompleted и в App.xaml.cs идет обработка события.

AuthViewModel.cs

```
 public event Action LoginCompleted;
    public ICommand AuthCommand => new RelayCommand(o => AuthMethod());


    public void AuthMethod()
    {
        LoginCompleted?.Invoke();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
```

App.xaml.cs

```
private LoginWindow Window { get; set; }
    private MainWindow CustomWindow { get; set; }
    public MainLoginVIewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        MainViewModel = new MainLoginVIewModel(LoginViewModel);
        LoginViewModel.OnAuthorize += LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize;
        Window = new LoginWindow { DataContext = MainViewModel };
        Window.Show();
    }

    private void LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize(object sender, LoginEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsAuthorized)
        {
            CustomWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = new ContentViewModel(e.User) };
            CustomWindow.Show();
            Window.Close();
        }

    }
```

Тоесть нажимая на кнопку в LoginControl должно срабатывать событие в App.xaml.cs
Если я что то не то делаю подскажите как реализовать правильней.

Если нужно еще скину кода

RegisterControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding User}" Width="100" Height="100"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

RegisterViewModel.cs

```
class RegisterViewModel : VM
{
    private string user;
    public string User
    {
        get => user;
        set => Set(ref user, value);
    }
}
```

ViewModel главного окна авторизации у меня оно называется MainLoginViewModel

```
RegisterViewModel regVM;
    public MainLoginVIewModel(LoginViewModel loginVM)
    {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(Test);
        regVM = new RegisterViewModel();
        CurrentContent = loginVM;
    }

    private VM currentContent;
    public VM CurrentContent
    {
        get => currentContent;
        set => Set(ref currentContent, value);
    }

    public ICommand TestCommand { get; }
    private void Test()
    {
        CurrentContent = regVM;
    }
```

Comment: Как по мне тут неверно 3 вещи. 1. Вы всю логику размещаете в App, когда он должен быть простым звеном для первичной обработки некой вспомогательной логики самой программы при старте/закрытие. Подписываться там на события не есть хорошо. 2. Вы нарушаете MVVM,  по MVVM вы не должны работать с контролами через код, для этого используются VM и привязки. У вас же, на сколько я понял, идет инициализация контрола через код (`s = (UserControl1)LoginWindow.Hello.Content;`). 3. Frame, тоже не очень верный подход. Как по мне он совершенно не годиться для показа контролов...

Comment: А вы можете поптробнее и ввиде ответа все 3 пункта написать? Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если так бегло посмотреть на ваше описание, то у вас тут как минимум 3 проблемы:

1. Вы довольно много логики делаете в App, это не очень удачное решение. Мне кажется, что там это даже не логично размещать. Сделайте для таких целей отдельную VM, которая все обработает, зачем же в APP...
2. В MVVM нельзя работать с контролами через код, если у вас есть скажем TextBox с именем `x:Name="textBox1"` и вы хотите задать ему текст таким путем: `textBox1.Text = "..."`, то тут вы напрямую работаете с этим элементом, что по правилам MVVM очень плохо! Для таких целей существую привязки (вы указываете `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}">`). Попробуйте убрать все имена у контролов, а то и вовсе убрать View часть. По паттерну MVVM ваше приложение должно работать даже без View.
3. `Frame`, это не очень хороший контрол для отображения содержимого в окне, он плохо встраивается в MVVM паттерн. Попробуйте использовать [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428226/220553) вариант и станет в разы легче!

---

Давайте попробуем сделать простой пример с реализацией всего, что я написал выше. Сделаем некий аналог авторизации с событием и сменой контента:

Я начну это все на пустом проекте, вы же смотрите сами...

И так, для начала нам понадобится два вспомогательных класса:

- `VM` - Он реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, а также мы по нему будем задавать текущий контент. У всех реализация разная, я лично возьму такой вариант:

  ```
  public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
              return false;

          field = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
          return true;
      }

      protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
  ```
- `RelayCommand` В MVVM не принято использовать события контролов (Click и подобные), их заменяют на привязки и что бы нам привязать логику на кнопку используют как раз команды (`ICommand`). `RelayCommand` соответственно является реализацией данного интерфейса. И опять же, у всех она разная, я лично возьму этот вариант:

  ```
  public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
  {
      private Action<T> action;
      public RelayCommand(Action<T> action) => this.action = action;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      #pragma warning disable CS0067
      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      #pragma warning restore CS0067
      public void Execute(object parameter) => action((T)parameter);
  }

  public class RelayCommand : ICommand
  {
      private Action action;
      public RelayCommand(Action action) => this.action = action;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      #pragma warning disable CS0067
      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      #pragma warning restore CS0067
      public void Execute(object parameter) => action();
  }
  ```

Отлично, подготовка завершена. Теперь сделаем две страницы и VM под них.

1. Страница авторизации. На ней мы попросим логин и пароль пользователя, а в ее VM мы реализуем команду, которая будет вызвана при попытки авторизации. Сама `LoginViewModel` будет наследоваться от класса `VM` (так мы сможем ее потом применить при смене контента, а также использовать INPC).

   - `LoginViewModel`:

     ```
     public class LoginViewModel : VM
     {
         public event EventHandler<LoginEventArgs> OnAuthorize;

         public ICommand LoginCommand { get; }

         public LoginViewModel()
         {
             LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(Authorize);
         }

         private string user;
         public string User
         {
             get => user;
             set => Set(ref user, value);
         }

         private string password;
         public string Password
         {
             get => password;
             set => Set(ref password, value);
         }

         private void Authorize()
         {
             if (User?.ToLower() == "test" && Password?.ToLower() == "123")
             {
                 OnAuthorize?.Invoke(this, new LoginEventArgs(User, true, "Успешная авторизация!"));
             }
             else
             {
                 OnAuthorize?.Invoke(this, new LoginEventArgs(User, false, "Неверный логин или пароль!"));
             }
         }
     }
     ```
   - `LoginEventArgs` - это данные события (`EventArgs`), простой класс, который содержит структуру передаваемых данных в этом событии:

     ```
     public class LoginEventArgs : EventArgs
     {
         public string User { get; }
         public bool IsAuthorized { get; }
         public string Message { get; }

         public LoginEventArgs(string user, bool isAuthorized, string message)
         {
             User = user;
             IsAuthorized = isAuthorized;
             Message = message;
         }
     }
     ```
   - `LoginView` - Это View нашей авторизации, всего два поля и кнопка, все привязываем к свойствам из `LoginViewModel`. Сама View является пользовательским элементом управления (`UserControl`):

     ```
     <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition/>
             <RowDefinition/>
             <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
             <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Логин: "/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Пароль: "/>
         <TextBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding User}" Width="100"/>
         <TextBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Password}" Width="100"/>
         <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="0 5" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Войти" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
     </Grid>
     ```
2. Страница с контентом, который мы покажем после авторизации. Делаем все в точности по аналогии с `LoginView`:

   - `ContentViewModel` - Самая простейшая ViewModel в которой я для примера буду содержать всего одно свойство. ViewModel должна наследоваться от класса `VM`, иначе не сможем задать как контент:

     ```
     public class ContentViewModel : VM
     {
         public string Title { get; set; } = "У нас получилось!";
     }
     ```
   - `ContentView` - View нашего основного контента. Является `UserControl`, содержит всего лишь привязанный `TextBlock`:

     ```
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
     ```

Теперь давайте поработаем над основным окном нашего приложения (`MainWindow`). Для него мы сделаем тоже свою ViewModel, назовем `MainViewModel` и в ней мы все это объединим:

```
public class MainViewModel : VM
{
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        LoginViewModel.OnAuthorize += LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize;
        CurrentContent = LoginViewModel;
    }

    private VM currentContent;
    public VM CurrentContent
    {
        get => currentContent;
        set => Set(ref currentContent, value);
    }

    private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get => message;
        set => Set(ref message, value);
    }

    private void LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize(object sender, LoginEventArgs e)
    {
        Message = $"[{e.User}] {e.Message}";
        CurrentContent = e.IsAuthorized ? (VM) new ContentViewModel() : LoginViewModel;
    }
}
```

Можно заметить, что мы создаем свойство ViewModel авторизации, в конструкторе инициализируем, подписываемся на событие и для примера задаем как основной контент нашего окна. В обработчики события я для примера формирую сообщение, которое в присваиваю созданному свойству.

Теперь само `MainWindow`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ContentViewModel}">
            <view:ContentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
            <view:LoginView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="10" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        </Border>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContent}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

С помощью `DataTemplate` связываем каждую ViewModel со своей View. Также выводим сообщение (обычный `TextBlock`, который привязан к свойству `Message`), ну и контент страницы (им мы заменяем `Frame`), задаем мы его с помощью `ContentPresenter`.

Осталось нам задать `DataContext`, сделаем мы это переписав немного `App`:

- В `App.xaml` убираем `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`.
- В `App.xaml.cs` переопределяем `OnStartup`:

  ```
  private MainWindow Window { get; set; }
  public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
      Window = new MainWindow{DataContext = MainViewModel};
      Window.Show();
  }
  ```

Все, запускаем и любуемся проделанной работой:

[image: Result]

Вот так, довольно просто, мы избавились от ужасного `Frame`, использовали событие и вывели разное содержимое в одно окно. Заметьте, мы не разу не обратились к элементу какой либо View, мы можем их вообще убрать и наша логика будет спокойно жить свой жизнью. Вот это разбитие по слоям и есть MVVM! Вы главное поймите принцип, как все это работает и дальше пойдет все как по маслу! Удачи!

---

Если у нас разные окна, то самый простой вариант, это сделать следующее:

1. Перепишем MainVewModel, а точней его конструктор, пусть он принимает LoginViewModel:

   ```
   public MainViewModel(LoginViewModel loginVM)
   {
       LoginViewModel = loginVM;
       CurrentContent = LoginViewModel;
   }
   ```
2. Перепишем App. Тут нам надо инициализировать LoginVM, MainVM, подписаться на события, в событие сделать логику открытия/закрытия и задать свойства окон:

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       private MainWindow Window { get; set; }
       private CustomWindow CustomWindow { get; set; }
       public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
       public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }

       protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnStartup(e);
           LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
           MainViewModel = new MainViewModel(LoginViewModel);
           LoginViewModel.OnAuthorize += LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize;
           Window = new MainWindow{DataContext = MainViewModel};
           Window.Show();
       }

       private void LoginViewModelOnOnAuthorize(object sender, LoginEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.IsAuthorized)
           {
               CustomWindow = new CustomWindow { DataContext = LoginViewModel };
               CustomWindow.Show();
               Window.Close();
               return;
           }

           MainViewModel.Message = $"[{e.User}] {e.Message}";
       }
   }
   ```

Все, теперь при запуске у нас откроется MainWindow с контентом авторизации и если авторизация успешна, то MainWindow закроется и заместо него появится CustomWindow (другое наше окно).

[image: Window Result]

Comment: Есть вопрлс 1 мне после тогоькак авторизация прошла успешно нужно закрывать LoginView и открывать MainWindow. Вот я не знаю как это сделать не использую App.xaml.cs

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я не совсем понимаю для чего вам окно, но да ладно. У вас есть два варианта. 1. Создать свой сервис для отображения окон, который будет наследоваться от интерфейса, этот интерфейс передать в LoginVM и там все обрабатывать. 2. Использовать App как вы и использовали ранее, но только разгрузить его от ненужной логики. (1. В OnStartup оставить только инициализацию VM,  первого окна (авторизация?), его Show и подписку на событие. 2. Убрать подписку на `Loaded` событие (оно лишнее). 3. В обработчике события авторизации делать `.Show()` главного окна и `.Close()` окна авторизации.).

Comment: Смотрите есть 2 окна LoginWindow и MainWindow. В окне LoginWindow есть 2 контролла LoginControl и RegisterControl. И вот когда авторизациия завершилась нужно закрывать LoginWindow и открывать MainWindow.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Просто поправка: У вас во 2 случае когда пишешь не правильный логин то ничего не происходит. На будущее чтоб не задавать вопросов можете поправить пожалуйста, если не трудно.

Comment: Вот честно последний вопрос. Я бы хотел добавить кроме LoginView еще и RegisterView. <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RegisterViewModel}">
                <local:RegisterControl/>
            </DataTemplate>

Comment: Но почему то в RegisterView не работает Binding. Как все красиво сделать?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я вам без кода не скажу в чем проблема. Что говорит [отладка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874490/220553)? Какой код в View и модели? А также вы написали `еще и RegisterView`, а пишите `RegisterControl`, с названием все верно? В общем, мне нужен код (можно в вопрос, можно куда то залить, можно проект архивом, как вам удобней будет) и что пишет в консоль при выводе этого контрола.

Comment: С названиями все нормально RegisterView я написал чтоб вам легче понять было а так у меня RegisterControl. В окне авторизации есть кнопка к которой команда привязана которая меняет CurrentContent на RegisterViewModel. появляется RegisterControl но Binding не работает почему-то. В консоль ничего не выдает.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Что то вы упускаете. И почему то мне кажется, что где то вы пересоздаете главную `DataContext` (догадки). В этой части кода проблем нет.

Comment: Я добавил измененный App.xaml.cs и еще ViewModel окна авторизации

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Попробовал я все сделать также, как и у вас, проблем не выявил. Вы можете сделать пример с данной проблемой, что бы я смог воспроизвести это у себя?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QXnqtsq9rRthapzP9bsbHcNb0DeBu4i5

Comment: Весь код который есть. Это если что тестовый код.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков У вас все привязки работают как положено. Проблема в том, что вы User то привязали, а значение задать?)

Comment: Хахах точно, а код нормально выглядит не костыль?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Ну я вижу только почти свой код) Единственное замечание, это все в одной куче. Разместите все по папкам (View/Model/ViewModel) и будет в разы красивее и легче по восприятию!

Comment: Это да! В основном проекте все по полочкам расположено а это чтоб не засорять основной

Comment: Подскажите плиз. попытался выполнить у себя, но к сожалению VS ругается на: ``` DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ContentViewModel}"> <view:WindowContent/> </DataTemplate> <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
```
Ошибка "vm" является не объявленным пространством имен.Где его нужно объявить?

Comment: @ИгорьАлексеенко [Пространства имен](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/2.4.php) в XAML объявляются в самом верху документа, там строки вида: `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"`.

Comment: в какое место в проекте лучше всего поместить класс `LoginEventArgs`? В какую-нибудь папку `services` или типо того? или в папку `models`?

Comment: @Pekor А тут больше зависит от конкретной логики, вот допустим в примере, я просто работаю с кнопочками и данными UI, из-за чего мне достаточно VM слоя. А вот если это был бы полноценный сервер (например сайт с API), то это уже был бы Model слой, который имел бы все необходимое в себе. Что касается сервисов, то опять же, зависит от вашего конкретного случая проектирования, допустим в [таком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) подходе, можно это вынести в отдельный проект и внедрить как сервис.