# Смена содержимого окна WPF после обработки события

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Начал изучать паттерн MVVM для использования в программе. В частности, сейчас есть пустой каркас MainWindow с ContentPresenter и две View - AuthView, MainView. Соответственно есть и ViewModel каждой. При старте программы в окно сразу загружается AuthView (скриншот ниже).

[image: Форма авторизации]

Желаемый результат - по нажатию кнопки выполняется обращение к серверу, получение ответа. Если ответ положительный - эти элементы исчезают и сюда грузится MainView. И что-то я совсем запутался, где разместить эту функцию взаимодействия с сервером, и как при получении именно положительного ответа в функции сменить View. Весь код приведен далее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добиться этого результата?
То, что есть, сделал по различным статьям и примерам реализации, ещё разобрался слабо, так что заранее извиняюсь за ошибки, буду рад, если укажете на них.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="QRScanner.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QRScanner"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="QRSCanner" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="OutputView" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using QRScanner.ViewModels;
using QRScanner.Views;

namespace QRScanner
{
    public interface IMainWindowsCodeBehind
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Показ сообщения для пользователя
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">текст сообщения</param>
        void ShowMessage(string message);

        /// <summary>
        /// Загрузка нужной View
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="view">экземпляр UserControl</param>
        void LoadView(ViewType typeView);
    }

    public enum ViewType
    {
        Authorization,
        Main
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindowsCodeBehind
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //загрузка стартовой View
            LoadView(ViewType.Authorization);
        }

        public void LoadView(ViewType typeView)
        {
            switch (typeView)
            {
                case ViewType.Authorization:
                    //загружаем вьюшку, ее вьюмодель
                    AuthView view = new AuthView();
                    AuthViewModel vm = new AuthViewModel(this);
                    //связываем их м/собой
                    view.DataContext = vm;
                    //отображаем
                    this.OutputView.Content = view;
                    break;
                case ViewType.Main:
                    MainView viewF = new MainView();
                    MainViewModel vmF = new MainViewModel(this);
                    viewF.DataContext = vmF;
                    this.OutputView.Content = viewF;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void ShowMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }
}
```

AuthView.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="QRScanner.Views.AuthView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QRScanner.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="login_lbl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10 0" Content="Логин:"></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="login_box" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10 0" Width="200"></TextBox>
        <Label x:Name="pass_lbl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0" Content="Пароль:"></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="pass_box" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0" Width="200"></TextBox>
        <Label x:Name="entry_status" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Auth_status}"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="authorize" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding LoadMainViewCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="{Binding Auth_status}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="30 10" Content="Войти" Click="authorize_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

AuthView.xaml.cs

```
    using QRScanner.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace QRScanner.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для AuthView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AuthView : UserControl
    {
        public AuthView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void authorize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (login_box.Text == "1")
                entry_status.Content = "OK";
            else
                entry_status.Content = "NO";
        }
    }
}
```

AuthViewModel.cs

```
   using QRScanner.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QRScanner.ViewModels
{
    class AuthViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private IMainWindowsCodeBehind _MainCodeBehind;
        private string auth_status;

        public AuthViewModel(IMainWindowsCodeBehind codeBehind)
        {
            if (codeBehind == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(codeBehind));

            _MainCodeBehind = codeBehind;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Переход к главному отображению
        /// </summary>
        private RelayCommand _LoadMainViewCommand;
        public RelayCommand LoadMainViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _LoadMainViewCommand = _LoadMainViewCommand ??
                  new RelayCommand(OnLoadMainView, CanLoadMainView);
            }
        }
        private bool CanLoadMainView()
        {
            return true;
        }
        private void OnLoadMainView()
        {
            _MainCodeBehind.LoadView(ViewType.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

MainView.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="QRScanner.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QRScanner.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="test" Content="Hello!"></Label> 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using QRScanner.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QRScanner.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private IMainWindowsCodeBehind _MainCodeBehind;

        public MainViewModel(IMainWindowsCodeBehind codeBehind)
        {
            if (codeBehind == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(codeBehind));

            _MainCodeBehind = codeBehind;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странное у вас тут только то, что вы обращаетесь к View элементам из VM слоя, что является грубым нарушением MVVM (ибо слой View должен быть совершенно независим от чего либо из слоя VM), уберите все `x:Name` и работайте с привязками. Также у кнопки `authorize` у вас зачем то идет привязка к команде и событию `Click`, оставьте что то одно (в строгом MVVM события по типу `Click` являются нарушением). По поводу самого вопроса, мне лично он не понятен. Просто сделайте метод, который будет отправлять на сервер данные и выводить нужную информацию исходя из ответа и вызывайте его в команде логина.

Comment: Исходя из ответа сервера мне нужно загружать MainView или оставлять AuthView, и я не знаю как реализовать именно это. Я только начал разбираться с паттерном. Если делать метод, то где именно - в AuthViewModel? И как реализовать загрузку другой View в случае положительного ответа сервера?

Comment: MVVM - это разделение всего на 3 слоя (Model/ViewModel/View), где Model отвечает за данные, View за UI, а ViewModel за связь этих двух слоев. Исходя из этого, правильней будет создать модель взаимодействия с сервером (отправка/получение данных) и в `AuthViewModel` взаимодействовать с ней. Если же это всего пару строк кода, то модель можно не создавать и в самом `AuthViewModel` реализовать работу с сервером. Отвечая на "Как реализовать загрузку другой View" - примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553).

Comment: Нашел в закромах своих [такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553), в нем я подробно описывал процесс смены "страницы" после "псевдо" успешной авторизации. Вам лишь остается переписать метод `Authorize()` для работы с сервером.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, @evgeniyz! Это то, что я искал и очень поможет разобраться в паттерне. Я использовал код из ваших "закромов". Но далее в приложении будет ещё много чего, поможете, если появятся ещё вопросы?=)

Comment: Без проблем, обращайтесь если будут вопросы. Этот вопрос я думаю мы тогда закроем как дубликат.

Comment: Здравствуйте, @EvgeniyZ! Возник вопрос касаемо этого же приложения. Если опираться на тот Ваш ответ, который мне помог, то как сделать, чтобы например по кнопке, размещенной в ContentView, программа возвращалась к странице авторизации? Пробовал это сделать по типу события OnAuthorize, создал подобный существующему классу LoginEventArgs. Соответственно, по той же логике добавляю в конструктор MainViewModel экземпляр ContentViewModel и вешаю функцию на его событие по типу OnAuthorize. Переход работает, но обратный переход со страницы логина на основную не происходит - зависает.