# WPF . Замена одного View на другое в рамках одного окна. @VladD отзовись

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Разжуйте мне как можно лучше как это сделать. Второй день топчусь на этой проблеме.  SOS>

Comment: И что же вам было не понятно в предыдущем вашем вопросе? Вроде вам все доходчиво объяснили, сказали, что в таком виде вопрос является явным дубликатом, рассказали что сделать для того, что бы это не происходило, но вы опять же задаете одно и тоже. Хорошо, вы в предыдущем вопросе говорили, что открывается новое окно, так дайте нам код, который покажет нам это, дайте свои наработки, попытки и будем от них отталкиваться. Но пока я могу вам опять же дать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861).

Comment: Почему нельзя просто написать, что нужно сделать ? Если бы я понял что нужно сделать из тех ответов что есть я бы не задавал это вопрос снова. Я второй день смотрю YouTube и серфю интернет . Можно просто написать схему действий для реализации того, что мне надо . Каких вам данных не хватает ? Я просто не понимаю что мне надо сделать вот и все.

Comment: Я не понимаю что такое ContentControl и как его использовать. Может я и задаю простые вопросы , но для меня как человека который знаком с WPF 2ой день непонятно многое и мне нужно чтобы кто то доходчиво обьяснил что куда и как.

Comment: Если вы человек, который знаком с WPF 2-й день, то вам рано еще лезть в MVVM и смену контента. Поймите для начала основы. Ну а так, посмотрите 2-ю ссылку, я там максимально подробно описал как подобное делать, если вам и это не понятно, то что нам писать здесь? А по поводу "почему нельзя просто написать" - читайте правила данного сайта. Если вопрос дубликат - то он закрывается как дубликат, зачем нам отвечать на явный дубликат, тем более не зная что вы конкретно от нас хотите и что вы пытались сделать сами?

Comment: @ВикторГилевич: А почему именно VladD? У нас тут, по словам администрации, много отвечающих по десктопному дотнету. По сути вопроса: слишком мало информации о том, что именно вы делаете и как. Не исключено, [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/10105) вам поможет, раз вы включили [mvvm] в метки.

Comment: Вот нашел то, где объясняется подробно что нужно сделать. Спасибо за помощь. https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/switching-between-wpf-xaml-views-using-mvvm-datatriggers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вас интересует ответ на мой вопрос, лучше гуглите его на английском. Там куча хороших объяснений это самое короткое из них.
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/switching-between-wpf-xaml-views-using-mvvm-datatriggers/