# WPF c# ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

Есть 2 юзер контрола: Логин панель и панель регистрации. У них есть свои ViewModel'и. Есть еще `AuthViewModel` и `BaseViewModel`, код:

**BaseViewModel**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        public static LoginViewModel L_GUI = new LoginViewModel();
        public static RegistrationViewModel R_GUI = new RegistrationViewModel();

        private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel;
        public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
        {
            get { return _selectedViewModel; }
            set
            {
                _selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
            }
        }
    }
```

**AuthViewModel**

```
public class AuthViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AuthViewModel()
        {
            SelectedViewModel = L_GUI;
        }

        private RelayCommand addCommand;
        public RelayCommand Registration
        {
            get
            {
                return addCommand ??
                    (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        SelectedViewModel = R_GUI;
                    }));
            }
        }


        private RelayCommand logincommand;
        public RelayCommand LogIn
        {
            get
            {
                return logincommand ??
                    (logincommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        SelectedViewModel = L_GUI;
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private RelayCommand logincommand;
        public RelayCommand Registration
        {
            get
            {
                return logincommand ??
                    (logincommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        SelectedViewModel = R_GUI;
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
```

**RegistrationViewModel**

```
 public class RegistrationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private RelayCommand logincommand;
        public RelayCommand LogIn
        {
            get
            {
                return logincommand ??
                    (logincommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        SelectedViewModel = R_GUI;
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Свойство `SelectedViewModel` определено в `BaseViewModel`, он отвечает за выбранный `ViewModel`. При смене `ViewModel`, сменяется и View. Так вот, при изменении свйоства `SelectedViewModel` из класса `LoginViewModel` и `RegistrationViewModel` само свойство вроде как меняется, но View не меняется. Я может не очень объяснил, могу скинуть проект.

Comment: `Свойство SelectedViewModel определено в BaseViewModel`, да, только реализовано оно в других классах. У вас нету некого одного класса, который отвечал бы за `SelectedViewModel`, у вас есть несколько классов, которые реализуют это свойство. Сделайте отдельный класс, который будет являться главным, в нем определите все необходимые свойства, а в классы, где требуется изменение свойства, передавайте ссылку через конструктор на главную VM.

Comment: Не могли бы вы оформить как ответ, пожалуйста. Может, если будет пример мне проще будет понять.

Comment: Я уже давал ответ с [подробным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553) решением вашей задачи, вы же его проигнорировали и пошли своим путем, что вы от меня ожидаете, переписывание того ответа? Да и если перепишу, то вы же не поймете небось опять. Да и зачем мне тратить на это время? Ну и не понятно что вы не понимаете, в чем трудности сделать в главной VM свойство `SelectedViewModel` (или вынести его отдельно в класс), в нужных классах принимать его главную VM через конструктор (`private ГлавVM VM; public LoginViewModel(главVM vm) {VM=vm;}`) и при инициализации `LoginViewModel(this)`

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!