# Закрыть страницу PageLogin после успешной авторизации

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void BLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var userObj = AppConnect.modeiOdb.Users.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.login == TxLogin.Text && x.password == TxPassword.Password);

                if (userObj == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Такого пользователя нет", "Ошибка Авторизации",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (userObj.id_user)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            MessageBox.Show("Здравствуйте администратор, " + userObj.userName + " !", "Уведомление",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            MessageBox.Show("Здравствуйте, " + userObj.userName + " !", "Уведомление",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information); break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Данные не обнаружены", "Уведомление",
                   MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Критическая работа приложения",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
            
        }
```

1

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource BackgroundWindowResource}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="250" OpacityMask="Black">
        <TextBlock Text="Введите логин"/>
        <TextBox Name="TxLogin"
                     Margin="0,5,0,5" />
        <TextBlock Text="Введите пароль"/>
        <PasswordBox Name="TxPassword"
                      Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Войти" 
                         Name="BLogin" Click="BLogin_Click" />
            <Button Content="Регистрация" Name="BReg" Click="Breg_Click" />

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppConnect.modeiOdb = new TitleStudentEntities();
            AppFrame.frameMain = frame1;
            frame1.Navigate(new PageLogin());


        }
    }
```

Нужно попасть на страницу PageMain.xaml

Comment: А про привязки и XAML не, мы не слышали... Ну чтож, берите тогда ваш компонент `Frame` (или что у вас там) и задавайте ему нужную страницу, в чем трудности?

Comment: у меня и так установлена нужная страница уже, вопрос в том, как перейти на другую если я авторизуюсь

Comment: Я вам уже ведь сказал как, не? Вы работаете с контролами напрямую, что в WPF совершенно не верный подход, из за этого, сейчас ваша страница = указанная страница в контроле, вот и указывайте туда при успешной авторизации `PageMain`.

Comment: Чтоб вы понимали, что делаете проект не так, я вам оставлю [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553) пример, где также реализуется авторизация, да только с привязками и XAML разметкой.