# Как не нарушая принципы MVVM открыть дочернее окно, скрыв родительское

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm, controls

В моем приложении после успешной авторизации должно открываться окно главного меню и соответственно скрываться окно авторизации. Как правильно реализовать это что бы не нарушить MVVM? Или может стоит делать все в одном окне и просто заменять контролы?

Comment: Простой гайд: https://youtu.be/pnG9CNfqZzA

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553 Ну а вообще, если открывать из VM слоя и др, то лучше [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553).

Comment: Многооконность не модно. Модно просто подменить вью в главном окне.