# C# WPF как реализовать окно ввода ключа

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как я могу сделать окно ввода ключа? Мне надо сделать так, чтобы при открытии программы, открывалось главное большое окно, которое проверяло бы наличие ключа, если его нет, должно открываться маленькое окно ввода ключа, с него должно быть невозможным убрать фокус, только закрыть его, но если его закрывают, вся программа останавливается. Как сделать подобное, чтобы не делать окно ввода ключа главным?

P.S конечно, я понимаю, что всё равно будет возможным закрыть только одно окно, но в главном окне, при действиях, я всё равно буду проверять ключ)

Comment: [Window.ShowDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553

Comment: Зачем вам 2 окна, когда можно и модно все делать в одном?

Comment: @aepot вы имеет ввиду Поп Ап? или просто менять контент?

Comment: вариантов куча :)