# C# WPF Отсутствует подписка на событие авторизации

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события, viewmodel

Делаю переход с `UserContol'а` авторизации на `UserControl` главной страницы по [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898835/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-c-wpf-mvvm/898861#898861) примеру.

Возможно где-то что-то проглядел, но после отладки выяснилось, что на событие `OnAuthorize` никто не подписан и поэтому оно не отрабатывает, код ниже:

`ViewModel` для авторизации:

```
public class AuthorizationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        //Само событие
        public event EventHandler<LoginEventArgs> OnAuthorize;

       ...

        public ICommand EnterCommand { get; }
        public AuthorizationViewModel()
        {
            EnterCommand = new RelayCommand(Authorize);
        }

        private void Authorize(object o)
        {
            using (ChessTrainerContext ctx = new ChessTrainerContext())
            {
                if (ctx.Users.Where(u => u.Login == this.Login && u.Password == this.Password).Any())
                    //Вызов события (тут почему-то null)
                    OnAuthorize?.Invoke(this, new LoginEventArgs(this.Login, true));              
            }
        }
    }

    public class LoginEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Login { get; }
        public bool IsAuthorized { get; }

        public LoginEventArgs(string login, bool isAuthorized)
        {
            Login = login;
            IsAuthorized = isAuthorized;
        }
    }
```

`ViewModel` окна, на котором расположены `UserControl'ы` и в котором я подписываюсь на событие:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AuthorizationViewModel authorizationViewModel { get; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            authorizationViewModel = new AuthorizationViewModel();
            //подписываюсь на событие
            authorizationViewModel.OnAuthorize += AuthorizationViewModelOnOnAuthorize;
            CurrentContent = authorizationViewModel;
        }

        private BaseViewModel currentContent;
        public BaseViewModel CurrentContent
        {
            get => currentContent;
            set { currentContent = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private void AuthorizationViewModelOnOnAuthorize(object sender, LoginEventArgs e)
        {
            //проверка чтоб сменить UserControl
            CurrentContent = e.IsAuthorized ? (BaseViewModel)new ChessTrainerViewModel() : authorizationViewModel;
        }
    }
```

Ну и код App.xaml.cs, в котором вызывается MainWindow при запуске:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private MainWindow Window { get; set; }
        public MainWindowViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            Window = new MainWindow { DataContext = MainViewModel };
            Window.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Конструктор MainWindowViewModel вызывается хотяб? Где у вас `DataContext` задается?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ага, в App.xaml.cs, добавил в текст вопроса код

Comment: Чет я не думаю, что проблема в этом коде. Такое впечатление, будто вы повторно где-то инициализируете VM классы (может в XAML, может еще где), из-за чего и подписка сбрасывается. Попробуйте проследишь шаг за шагом что делает ваш код.

Comment: У меня в XAML UserControl'ов есть `DataContext`, а в примере нет, может ли быть из-за этого?

Comment: Ну это равноценно повторному `=new MainWindowViewModel()` например, что будет означать другой объект в DataContext. Так что да, это может повлиять. Вообще у вас должен быть один `DataContext` на все приложение, этого достаточно для почти всех задач.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ух ты, это открытие для меня, спасибо, ошибка была действительно в DataContext в xaml, но я почему-то думал что без указания не будут работать binding'и)