# Как абсолютно все закрыть окна и оставить одно окно Главное?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 3 окна

1 - Главное
2 и 3 модальные.

По умолчанию открывается окно 1 (с авторизацией)

Там вводим логин и пароль, и открывается уже другое окно 2 или 3 в зависимости какой логин или пароль. И при этом 1 окно при открытии другого скрывается.

В окнах  2 и 3 есть Frame, в них  есть кнопка код кнопки вот такой

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Вы уверены что хотите выйти из учётной записи?", "Информация",

       MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
       MessageBoxImage.Question);


        foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {                    
                if (window is AuthorizationWindow)
                {

                    TeacherStart teacher = new TeacherStart(1);                       
                    StartSchoolboy schoolboy= new StartSchoolboy(1);
                  

                    AuthorizationWindow authorization = new AuthorizationWindow();
                    authorization.Show();
                }
            }
         break;
```

И он срабатывает только 1 раз.

То есть если мы зашли под пользователем ... и открылось 2 окно, то код будет работать.

И если при этом мы вышли из 2 окна, и вводим логин и пароль и входим в 3 окно, то уже

окно не скрывается с таким же кодом, а только отображается окно 1

```
 public StartSchoolboy(int exit = 0)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        
        if(exit == 1)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }


 public TeacherStart(int exit = 0)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (exit == 1)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Какой же вы ерундой занимаетесь, ей богу, смотрю каждый ваш вопрос и думаю, "ну почему так, зачем человек сидит на WPF, если делает такое..?". Вот давайте по порядку, WPF это привязки, XAML, почему вы это не используете? Почему вы почти все пишете в коде? Далее, Frame - это ужаснейший компонент, который дает больше мороки, чем решение поставленной задачи. Затем, че за `int exit`? Почему это int а не bool, может быть больше 1 значение? Думаю нет... А не кажется странным то, что вы открываете окно, чтобы потом его сразу закрыть (если 1)? Я думаю да. А открывать все окна, чтоб оставить одно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  я в окно передаю параметр , если он равен 1 то окно закрывается что тут не понятного ?

Привязкой пользуюсь там где знаю как её использовать. В коде пишу не всё, а только то что через xaml  не знаю как сделать.

Comment: `что тут не понятного ?` - ну вы сами свой код посмотрите и поймите, что увидите? Допустим `public TeacherStart(int exit = 0)` - вы инициализируете класс, передав туда число, если оно 1, то после инициализации (расстановки всех компонентов в XAML) вы его закрываете. Ок, а что закрываете? То, что еще не было открыто? Ведь показ окна, это `Show` метод, который вызывается после конструктора (`new TeacherStart(1).Show()`), вот посмотрите на этот код внимательно, что я дал, после `new` идет конструктор, там сразу закрытие, а после уже показ окна. Ну не кажется, что закрытие тут бесполезно?

Comment: Посмотрите на код перебора окон `if (window is AuthorizationWindow)`, если окно авторизации, то создаем 2 новых окна (но не показываем), затем создаем окно авторизации и показываем его. Уверены в логике? `где знаю как`...`через xaml не знаю как` - вот очень большой совет, начните в этом разбираться, а не задавать такие вот вопросы. Не знаете как сделать в XAML, спросите, поможем, но сейчас у вас костыли на костылях, вы используете WPF как WinForms, зачем тогда он вам, если вы не используете его по максимуму? Поизучайте [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553).