# Вывод одного пользователя с его личным кабинетом

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

у меня есть проект WPF, в котором есть страница с личным кабинетом пользователя, я вывожу одного пользователя из бд SQLite с помощью SqlDataAdapter. Я хочу сделать так чтобы после авторизации любого другого пользователя  появлялся его страничка с личным кабинетом где выводится его же Login. То есть сейчас у меня вывод происходит правильно!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну я хочу чтобы новый зарегистрированный пользователь, допустим с ником Oleg, после окна авторизации попадал в свой личный кабинет где бы выводилось Login:Oleg. Как реализовать такую логику чтобы Авторизованный пользователь попадал в свой кабинет со свойм логином и другими данными. Заранее спасибо. Я новичок в WPF. Внизу будет весь мой код

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace DrivingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserPageWIndow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserPageWIndow : Window
    {

        private SQLiteConnection DB;

        public UserPageWIndow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
            DB = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = DrivingScl.db");
            DB.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, login FROM Users WHERE id = 3";
            SQLiteDataReader SQL = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (SQL.HasRows)
            {
                while (SQL.Read() )
                {
                    nam2.Text += "Логин :" + SQL["Login"];
                }
            }
            else nam2.Text = "Нет таких";
        }
    }
}
```

Это окно с выводом 1 пользователя

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DrivingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для AuthWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AuthWindow : Window
    {
        public AuthWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Auth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string login = textBoxLogin.Text.Trim();
            string pass = passBox.Password.Trim();

            if (login.Length < 5)
            {
                textBoxLogin.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                textBoxLogin.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            }
            else if (pass.Length < 5)
            {
                passBox.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                passBox.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            } else
            {
                textBoxLogin.ToolTip = "";
                textBoxLogin.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                passBox.ToolTip = "";
                passBox.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

                User authUser = null;
                using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
                {
                    authUser = db.Users.Where(b => b.Login == login && b.Pass == 
                    pass).FirstOrDefault();  
                }

                if(authUser != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Всё хорошо!");
                    
                    UserPageWIndow userPageWindow = new UserPageWIndow();
                    userPageWindow.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели что-то некорректно");
            }  
        }

        private void Button_Reg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Это окно с входом пользователя в свой кабинет, после нажатия на кнопку(Вход в кабинет) он переходит на страницу с личным кабинетом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите, кто работа с авторизации пользователя с его личными данными, я новичок по изучению WPF

Comment: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(login);` - передаешь логин при вызове окна, в конструкторе MainWindow обрабатываешь действия с логином

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/898861/220553

Comment: Отмечу, что вы не используете в своём коде `SqlDataAdapter`. | То, что вы используете в первом файле можно называть "чистый (или сырой) ADO.NET".

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

userPageWindow.log.Text = authUser.Login; - эту строчку после MessageBox, log - название TextBlock

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)